# Any way to automate getting metrics from the Youtube Analytics endpoint?

Tags: etl, youtube-analytics-api

I'm currently creating a dashboard for an organization to display engagement metrics from several of their platforms (so far, Youtube and Facebook). I've written scripts in Python that call several endpoints in order to get the specific metrics I need from Youtube and Facebook.

The only way that I've found to get the average view percentage (what percentage viewers are making it into the videos on average) and average view duration in seconds by video is through the Youtube Analytics endpoint. Unfortunately, because of OAuth2 authentification, I need to have this specific script that gets these 2 metrics in a jupyter notebook so that I can click the link and manually go through the authorization process.

My question is, is there any way, through this endpoint or maybe even the reporting API to get the same data but without having to manually log in every time? I'm getting the other metrics in scripts that are triggered by a cron job, but it would be awesome to be able to automate this part as well.